# Android - Destroying Activity after Time Elapse

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

I trying to code an activity (buildImage) so that is automatically "closes" after a specified time. I am using the CountDown timer class, but am having no success. It simply does nothing, no errors, or anything else.

What might the issue be (the Looper.prepare() line is there to prevent an error from being thrown)

Here is my code:

```
    package midamcorp.com.burgerkingapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class buildImage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
private ImageButton back;
    ImageView buildContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_build_image);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        buildContainer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullSizeImage);
        back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.backButton);



        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                new CountDownTimer(1000, 0) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        back.callOnClick();
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Intent i = getIntent();
        if (i.hasExtra("position"))

        {
            int position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");
            int lto = i.getExtras().getInt("lto");
            int location = i.getExtras().getInt("location");
            gridAdapter adapter = new gridAdapter(this, lto, location);




            Bitmap buildImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(adapter.buildImages.get(position), 0, adapter.buildImages.get(position).length);
            buildContainer.setImageBitmap(buildImage);

        } else

        {


            byte[] imageId = i.getByteArrayExtra("imageID");
            Bitmap buildImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageId, 0, imageId.length);
            buildContainer.setImageBitmap(buildImage);

        }
    }
    }
```

Logically, I thought it would start a countdown once the activity is launched, then, after 1 second, call the click listener of the back button, thus finishing the activity, but it is obviously not so.

Thanks much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your thread code to this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        finish();
    }
}, 1000L);
```

You have to be aware of the activity lifecycle as well.